# Converting Setting File to Hash

Tags: ruby

I have a settings file and I am reading it with file read and getting a string that I want to convert into a hash for easier usage.

How can I convert the following:

```
string="key1=value1\nkey2=value2"
```

Into:

```
{"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"}
```

Comment: The logic is not clear. Where does `"value2"` come from?

Comment: Misspelled value in the string. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string.split("\n").map{|s| s.split("=")}.to_h
```

---

First split around new lines.

```
string.split("\n")
#=> ["key1=value1", "key2=v vlue2"]
```

Next, split each strings around `=`

```
string.split("\n").map{|s| s.split("=")}
#=> [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "v vlue2"]]
```

Next, convert the array of 2-element arrays into Hash by calling `to_h` method.

```
string.split("\n").map{|s| s.split("=")}.to_h
#=> {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"v vlue2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[*string.split(/[\n=]/)]   # => {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}
```